# How can fix this wamp server , phpmyadmin page error?

Tags: php, wampserver

Error :

```
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. <a href="Documentation.html#faqmysql" target="documentation"><img class="icon" src="./themes/pmahomme/img/b_help.png" width="11" height="11" alt="Documentation" title="Documentation" /></a>
```

my error is that. How can I fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try [installing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) mysqli?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar You should read the Mysqli documentation http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php. The 3rd param of the mysqli class is the database name. There's also a `select_db()` method on that class and `mysqli_select_db()`.

Comment: @SenorAmor thanks for answer , but could you delete your answer , because I want to delete my question but I cant ,it says you cant delete it it is a answered question